# Estimating $\pi$

Tags: probability

Lazzerini determined that value of $\pi$ from Buffon's needle problem. Use these and central limit theorem to estimate the probability that a result could be as good as his. Compare this with the true binomial probabilities.

I don't think I quiet understand the question. Any hints on how to start will be appreciated.

Edit 1:

To apply central limit theorem, we require a sequence of random variables. I'm unsure how to define those random variables. Also, his approximation was accurate to six digits. So do I need to find the probability of getting the value of $\pi$ accurate to 6 digits in 3408 tosses?

Edit 2:

Here is what I've tried:

Let $X_n$ be relative frequency of intersections in $n$ tosses. By law of large numbers, $X_n \longrightarrow \frac {2}{\pi}$ in probability. Further, let $f(x) = \frac{2}{x}$. Then as  $f$ is continuous, $\frac {2}{X_n} \longrightarrow \pi$ in probability.

Lazzarini tossed the needle 3408 times and got the estimate correct to six decimals.

Let $\pi^*$ denote his estimate of $\pi$ after 3408 tosses.

$\pi^*$ = $\frac{2}{X_n}$

$P(|\pi^*-3.141592|\leq 0.0000005)$ = $|P(\frac{2}{3.1415925}\leq X_n \leq \frac{2}{3.1415915})|$

Now, $X_n$ is equivalent in distribution to $N(p,\frac{p(1-p)}{n})$, $p=\frac{2}{\pi}$.

Therefore, $X_n$ is equivalent in distribution to $N(\frac{2}{\pi},\frac{2(\pi-2)}{n\pi^2})$

With $n=3408$,

$P(|\pi^*-3.141592|\leq 0.0000005)$ = $\phi(\frac{\frac{2}{3.1415915}-\frac{2}{\pi}}{\sqrt{\frac{2(\pi-2)}{3408\pi^2}}})-\phi(\frac{\frac{2}{3.1415925}-\frac{2}{\pi}}{\sqrt{\frac{2(\pi-2)}{3408\pi^2}}})$, where $\phi$ is cdf of standard normal distribution.

$P(|\pi^*-3.141592|\leq 0.0000005)$ = $\phi(2.837336878 \times 10^{-5})-\phi(3.777650218 \times 10^{-6})$ = $9.81226834 \times 10^{-6}$

This probability seems pretty less than what I expected. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You should add the tag 'self-study' to this question.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). You might also add some context (eg, Lazzerini, pi, Buffon's problem, etc).

Comment: Perhaps a little intuition might help you.  The standard deviation of $X_n$, given by $\sqrt{2(\pi-2)/(n\pi^2)}$, is approximately $0.008$.  I would therefore be impressed for this experiment to obtain a value of $2/\pi$ that is correct to three decimal places, surprised by four d.p., and astonished by five or more d.p.  As far as your calculation goes, $\pi^{*}$ has a decidedly non-Normal distribution.  Do all your calculations in terms of $X_n$ instead.